# Google Charts - Table Chart Not Displaying Data

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts - Table Chart. My table has suddenly stopped displaying any data. It was working fine the last time I worked on this, about 5-7 days ago. The table will display with the correct column headers, but no data. Here is the json being returned from my AJAX call (a C# service using Google.DataTable to generate the json):

```js
{
    "cols": [
        {
            "type": "string",
            "id": "Business Name",
            "label": "Business Name"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "id": "Location",
            "label": "Location"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "<a href='/Advertiser/DisplayPage?advertiserId=8'>Acem Birding Tours</a>"
                },
                {
                    "v": "Cincinnati, OH"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I ran this json through json Lint and it is valid json.

My JavaScript function that draws the chart/table looks as follows:

```js
function createSearchResultsTable() {
    var options = {
        // Create some options for the displaying of the table
        page: 'enable',
        allowHtml: true,
        width: 800,
        pageSize: 20,
        showRowNumber: true
    };

    // Get the list of guides
    $.getJSON('/Home/SearchForGuide', { country: selectedCountry }, function (jsonData) {
    }).success(function (jsonData) {

        data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('resultsTable'));
        table.draw(data, options);

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Like I said, about 5-7 days ago, this was working exactly as expected and data was being displayed. Now the same row of data, shown above, is not being displayed. Can anyone see what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. When you say "*..about 5-7 days ago, this was working exactly as expected and data was being displayed*" then I strongly suspect the reason is a change in your headers, eg. how you load google visualization. In order to show the table chart types, you must initialise google visualization like this

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["table"]});
```

or

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages:["corechart, table"]});
```

not

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

as I suspect you are doing :) Otherwise your code is fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7361pk4g/**